# Jquery Post Array Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Site accepts array data. But I get an unexpected token error

```
$.post("https://blabla.com/request.php", {
  shareable_attachment[share_params][title]:baslik
}, function(data, status) {
});
```

Comment: Your `data` object is invalid. What **exactly** should the request body look like, eg `someTitle=theValueOfBaslik`?

Comment: A `key` of an object must be a string. `shareable_attachment[share_params][title]` is not string. Try `var argsObj = {}; args[shareable_attachment[share_params][title]] = baslik;` and then `$.post(...,argsObj, ...)`